# Magento 2.1.9 - ReCaptcha Extension Error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9, captcha, http-error-500

I have added this extension to my project:

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha

The only code I modified is the system.xml in order to get a tab in the backend.

What happens now is that any time I enable the extension and I try to use the captcha, the webpage crashes after using it, as you can see:

[image]

Even though before it appears with a green tick:

[image]

Now, what they say where you get the keys from is this:

[image]

I got to paste two snippets somewhere in the code, but the thing is atleast as far as I saw, the guys at MageSpecialist, where I have taken the extension from, haven't coded any tags with:

```
<head></head>
```

or:

```
<form></form>
```

All this happens everywhere I place the reCaptcha.

So, **the questions are:**

1. Where do I have to add those snippets?
2. Has anyone faced that problem?
3. How can I fix it?